# Regular expression using hypens and digits

Tags: regex, language-agnostic

I want to create a regular expression in such a way that only hypens and digits must be allowed in the text box the criteria is

1. Hypen should not come in the first and last position
2. Hypen must have digits at both ends
3. There can be n number of hypens and digits in the text box

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you provide a set of example strings that it should match, that would probably help to make your intentions clearer.

Comment: Should it accept empty strings? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't believe it, I got it by giving a guess in regular expression i hope this will work fine.

```
(\d+(\d*\\-\d+)+\d*)|\d+
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a shortened version of @El Yobo's regex. You can replace `[0-9]` with `\d` and you can make the hyphen optional with `-?` to remove the special case of hyphenless strings.

```
^\d+(-?\d+)*$
```

http://ideone.com/SRqPW

Comment: +1, not just shorter, but more correct (as you've pointed out on my answer).  Using \d depends on your exact implementation (it's not standard), but it's very common; I stuck with [0-9] for maximum compatibility.

Comment: Although this still doesn't permit an empty string, perhaps `^(\d+(-?\d+)*)*$`?

Comment: `[0-9]` is also not strictly portable. `[[:digit:]]` or `[0123456789]` would be the most portable.

Answer (score 3):

This regular expression should do it:

```
^[0-9]+(-[0-9]+)*$
```

This will match one or more digits, that may be followed by zero or more sequences of a hyphen followed by one or more digits.

Comment: I **like** your answer: it just *looks* cleaner and more sensible than some of the others.  Do you use `[0-9]` because `\d` wasn’t around when you started, or is it because you want to make sure it doesn’t have match non-ASCII? The most careful regex coders are legimately concerned about that last one. We don’t really have a way to say “and all in the same script” for an *arbitrary script*, although for any given one it’s easy enough (well, not in Java till JDK7). But I kinda like `[0-9]` even if there are fancier solutions possible sometimes. It’s very clear what’s happening that way.

Comment: @tchrist: Since this question is tagged *language-agnostic* I prefer `[0-9]` as not all regular expression engines support the character class `\d` (namely the BRE and ERE of POSIX and GNU).

Answer (score 2):

I assume that an empty string is valid.  I'm not sure I understand your third clause; do you mean that n can be anything, or do you have to limit things to n occurrences?  I'm also not sure how many digits need to be at each end of a hyphen; is it any number one or greater, or exactly one?

The following regex allows a string like 1-9-129-2-293-23, for example.

```
^(([0-9]+-[0-9]+)|[0-9]+)*$
```

Because each subpattern must start and end with a digit, it's not necessary to have a digit match at each end outside the substring as in the other solutions posted here.

Comment: This doesn't match hyphen-less strings.

Comment: Downvoting mine, your answer is better :)

Answer (score 2):

Would this work?

```
(\d+\-)*\d+
```

Edit: Changed '+' to '*' as hyphens don't seem to be necessary.

Edit2: Fixed the regex to prevent double hyphens.

Answer (score 2):

```
^((\d+-)+\d+)*$
```

It says: you must start with a few digits, followed by a `-`. Repeat as many times as you like, then you must end with some more digits. That `*` at the end is there to allow empty strings.

Answer (score -2):

You could try using this regex: `.[\w-]*`

Comment: `\w` includes digits, letters, and underscore.