# Regular expression to match a password field in Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I am using `Asp.Net/C#`, I am using `RegularExpressionValidator` to match a password field.My requirement is that I need the user to enter a password which will be atleast 7 characters long and it can contain any combination of alphabets and numeric characters , however it should contain strictly one non-alphanumeric character , can anybody suggest me as to how I can achieve this.
Any suggestions are welcome.Thank you

Comment: I hope the below link will be useful

[Password validation][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4352025/regular-expression-using-hypens-and-digits

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
String[] words = { "Foobaar", "Foobar1", "1234567", "123Fooo", "Fo12!", "Foo12!", "Foobar123!", "!Foobar123", "Foo#bar123" };

foreach (String s in words) {

    Match word = Regex.Match(s, @"
          ^                        # Match the start of the string
            (?=                    # positive look ahead
                [\p{L}\p{Nd}]*     # 0 or more letters or digits at the start
                [^\p{L}\p{Nd}]     # string contains exactly one non-digit, non-letter
                [\p{L}\p{Nd}]*     # 0 or more letters or digits after the special character 
            $)                     # till the end of the string
            .{7,}                  # match 7 or more characters
          $                        # Match the end of the string
        ", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
    if (word.Success) {
        Console.WriteLine(s + ": valid");
    }
    else {
        Console.WriteLine(s + ": invalid");
    }
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

`\p{L}` is a unicode code point with the property "letter"

`\p{Nd}` is a unicode code point with the property "digit"

Comment: can I use this with an asp.net regularexpression validator

Comment: I don't know asp.net, but I tested it with c#, so since both is .net it should work.

Answer (score 1):

```
((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%]).{7,20})


(           # Start of group
  (?=.*\d)      #   must contains one digit from 0-9
  (?=.*[a-z])       #   must contains one lowercase characters
  (?=.*[A-Z])       #   must contains one uppercase characters
  (?=.*[@#$%])      #   must contains one special symbols in the list "@#$%"
              .     #     match anything with previous condition checking
                {7,20}  #        length at least 7 characters and maximum of 20 
)
```

Copied from [here](http://www.mkyong.com/regular-expressions/how-to-validate-password-with-regular-expression/).

Comment: can you suggest me to allow the user to enter only non aplhanumeric character

Comment: `[^\w\d]` regex should do it.

Comment: @freebird: You mean.. only 1 non-alphanumeric? I can edit the answer if that's what you need. Else, Jack's comment should do it.

Comment: @Jack i think it will words and digits , how do I include only one non alphanumeric character as well

Comment: @RobinMaben , I meant that it should contain words digits and only one nonalphanumeric character

Comment: @freebird: The `^` in Jack's suggestion means "Anything except".

Comment: @freebird: You can add `{1,}` after the expression where you need strictly one match.

Comment: @RobinMaben currently I am using this ^[(A-Z)(a-z)(0-9)]*$ for words and digits , how should I modify this

Comment: I think you're aiming for `^[(A-Z)(a-z)(0-9)]{1, }*$`? i.e. Only one non-alphanumeric character?. I haven't verified that though.

Comment: @RobinMaben `{1,0}` is the the same than `+` means 1 or more and you don't need grouping brackets inside a character class.

Comment: @stema: Thanks for pointing out. But I wasn't sure how to arrive at `1 only`.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following to match my needs `^([\w]*[(\W)]{1}[\d]*)$` , this allows a password to start with an alphabet any number of times , then the password must contain an non-alphanumeric character only 1 time , followed by a digits any number of times.

Comment: cool that you came up with an own solution. I assume that you do the length check then somewhere else. Some hints: `{1}` is superfluous, you simply don't need it, you don't need the round brackets inside a character class, when your char class has only one member you don't need a class, `\w` contains also the underscore and at last: you don't need the brackets around the whole expression. So you could simplify your expression to `^\w*\W\d*$ `

Comment: @Stema thanks a lot I will simplify the expression , My length check is done in the configuration file , the pattern I used in my answer will only allow passwords like abc@123 , xyz#456 etc.thanks